# UIContentSizeCategory availability check to fix "Cannot find type 'UIContentSizeCategory' in scope"

Tags: swiftui

I have a shared library (for mac and iOS app), and I'd like to use `UIContentSizeCategory` there. Since it is a part of `UIKit`, I added

```swift
import SwiftUI
#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit
#endif
```

to a file header and then declare my extension (to convert from SwiftUI to UIKit size category):

```swift
#if canImport(UIKit)
@available(iOS 8.0, macCatalyst 13.1, tvOS 9.0, *)
extension ContentSizeCategory {
    var uiContentSizeCategory: UIContentSizeCategory {
        switch self {
        case .extraSmall: return .extraSmall
        case .small: return .small
        case .medium: return .medium
        case .large: return .large
        case .extraLarge: return .extraLarge
        case .extraExtraLarge: return .extraExtraLarge
        case .extraExtraExtraLarge: return .extraExtraExtraLarge
        case .accessibilityMedium: return .accessibilityMedium
        case .accessibilityLarge: return .accessibilityLarge
        case .accessibilityExtraLarge: return .accessibilityExtraLarge
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: return .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: return .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge
        @unknown default:
            assertionFailure("Unknown ContentSizeCategory: \(self)")
            return .medium
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

However, I still get `Cannot find type 'UIContentSizeCategory' in scope` error when building this, even though I have checked platform availability of `UIContentSizeCategory` in docs and added `@available` check for these platforms.

How should I properly limit the availability of the extension to make it build?

Thanks for any advice! Tomas

**EDIT:** Very weird thing is that if I change the check to `#if !os(watchOS) && canImport(UIKit)`, it builds.

Why is that? Isn't `@available(iOS 8.0, macCatalyst 13.1, tvOS 9.0, *)` enough to exclude watchOS target?

Comment: Just this code snapshot compiled fine in macOS part, so probably the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @Asperi Very weird thing is that if I change the check to `#if !os(watchOS) && canImport(UIKit)`, it builds. Why is that? Isn't `@available(iOS 8.0, macCatalyst 13.1, tvOS 9.0, *)` enough to exclude watchOS target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't @available(iOS 8.0, macCatalyst 13.1, tvOS 9.0, *) enough to exclude watchOS target?

No, we have to add explicitly `@available(watchOS, unavailable)`

Like

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
@available(iOS 8.0, macCatalyst 13.1, tvOS 9.0, *)
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
extension ContentSizeCategory {
```

Comment: Aha! This is what I was missing! Apparently there is no terse (one line) way to write both availability and unavailability into a single `@available` declaration, right?